# app freezes on deletion of last row in section ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I created an app that used NSManagedDocument and NSFetchedResultsController to populate a NSTableViewController. In ios6 when I deleted the last row of a section it just disappeared and carried on as expected whereas in ios7 the app just freezes and seems to be consuming memory exponentially. I have used the code from the Stanford CS193p lectures to allow the fetchedresultscontroller and tableviewcontroller to combine.

Is this problem a bug in ios7 or does older code need to be updated?

thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that despite deleting the row, the section still exists in memory, try deleting the section using the following method:

```
    [self.table deleteSections:<#(NSIndexSet *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I slide the cell to the left to delete it, doing it changes the editing property of the tableview. I had changed the setEditing method to do some custom code for a previous version and so for some reason it kept creating NSIndexPaths. Hope this helps someone in the future!